# How can i access a arraylist from anywhere in my project and interact with only one object in it

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I have an assignment to make a gui for a bank app that has 5 functions balance,withdraw,deposit,exit and to make a new customer. I had 2 classes first BankAccount and Customer. I made jframe windows for the gui but i am stuck i dont know how to make the deposit,withdraw and balance functions work. I want the user to enter their account number and based of that I call their account with their balance and allow them to deposit/withdraw and get balance,Idk know how to achieve this. *Customer created objects are stored in arraylist (one of the requirments for the assignment).

```
//MainPage gui
private void NCustBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
          NewCustomer Nmenu = new NewCustomer();
          Nmenu.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void DepositBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
          Deposit D=new Deposit();
          D.setVisible(true);


    }                                          

    private void ExtBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       System.exit(0);
    }                                      

    private void WithdrawBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
         Withdraw T=new Withdraw();
          T.setVisible(true);
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
       MainPage Menu= new MainPage();
       Menu.setVisible(true);
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainPage().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private javax.swing.JButton BalBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton DepositBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton ExtBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPanel HeadingPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton NCustBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton WithdrawBtn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
//BankAccount Class
public class BankAccount {

    private int accountNumber;
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount(int randnum1) {
        accountNumber = randnum1;
        balance = 0;
    }

    public BankAccount(int randnum1, double randNum2) {
        accountNumber = randnum1;
        balance = randNum2;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber() {

        return accountNumber;
    }


    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }


    public void deposit(double amt) {
        balance = balance + amt;
    }


    public String withdraw(double amt) {
        String result = "";

        if (amt <= balance) {
            balance = balance - amt;

            result = "Your balance is " + balance;
            return result;
        } else if (amt > balance) {
            result = ("You have insufficient funds to withdraw this amount");

        }
        return result;
    }

}


public class Customer {
    //Class attribute
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private BankAccount account;
    private String Month;
    private String Day;
    private String Year;
   ArrayList<Customer> CustomerList=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    //Constructor
    Customer(String fName, String lName){
        firstName=fName;
        lastName=lName;

    }
    //Overloaded Constructor
    Customer(String fName, String lName, BankAccount acc1)
    {
        firstName=fName;
        lastName=lName;
        account=acc1;
    }
    Customer(String fName, String lName, BankAccount acc1,String month,String day,String year)
    {
        firstName=fName;
        lastName=lName;
        account=acc1;
        Day=day;
        Month=month;
        Year=year;

    }


    public String getDay() {
        return Day;
    }
    public void setDay(String day )
    {
        this.Day=day;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return Month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        Month = month;
    }
    public String getYear()
    {
        return Year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        Year = year;
    }

    //Accessor to retrieve User's first name
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    //Mutator to set user entered information as first name
    public void setFirstName(String fName)
    {
        this.firstName=fName;
    }


    public String getLastNameName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }


    //Mutator to set user entered information as last name
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //Accessor to retrieve account information
    public BankAccount getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
//Mutator for BankAccount object
    public void setAccount(BankAccount account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}

//Gui that allows user to register as new customer
public class NewCustomer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewCustomer
     */
    public NewCustomer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        FnameLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        LnameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        LnameLBl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        FnameTxt1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        RegLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        RegisterBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        DOBLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        DOBMonth = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        DOBDay = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        DoBYearTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 255));

        FnameLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        FnameLbl.setText("First Name");

        LnameLBl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        LnameLBl.setText("Last Name");

        RegLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        RegLbl.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        RegLbl.setText("Registration");

        RegisterBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        RegisterBtn.setText("GENERATE");
        RegisterBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                RegisterBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DOBLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        DOBLbl.setText("Date Of Birth");

        DOBMonth.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "January", "Februrary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" }));
        DOBMonth.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DOBMonthActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DOBDay.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", " " }));
        DOBDay.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DOBDayActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DoBYearTxt.setText("Year");
        DoBYearTxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                DoBYearTxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        TextArea.setColumns(20);
        TextArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(TextArea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(RegLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 210, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(FnameLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(LnameLBl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(DOBLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(32, 32, 32)))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(FnameTxt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 190, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(LnameTxt))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(RegisterBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(DOBMonth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(DOBDay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(DoBYearTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(132, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(RegLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(FnameLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(FnameTxt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(LnameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(LnameLBl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(DOBLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(DOBMonth, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(DOBDay, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(DoBYearTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(RegisterBtn)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
ArrayList<Customer> CustomerList=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    private void RegisterBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String fName=FnameTxt1.getText();
        String lName=LnameTxt.getText();
        Random rand = new Random();
        String mont= DOBMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String day=DOBDay.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String year=DoBYearTxt.getText();



        int randnum1 = rand.nextInt(9000000);
        Double IntBal=500.00;
        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(randnum1, IntBal);
        Customer customer1=new Customer(fName,lName,account1,mont,day,year);
        CustomerList.add(customer1);


        TextArea.append("Thank you for registering with Dior Bank "+"" + fName +" "+ lName +" "+ "\n Your account number is" + " "+ randnum1);

    }                                           




    private void DOBMonthActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     String mont= DOBMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }                                        

    private void DOBDayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String day=DOBDay.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }                                      

    private void DoBYearTxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String year=DoBYearTxt.getText();
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewCustomer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewCustomer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> DOBDay;
    private javax.swing.JLabel DOBLbl;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> DOBMonth;
    private javax.swing.JTextField DoBYearTxt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel FnameLbl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField FnameTxt1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel LnameLBl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField LnameTxt;
    private javax.swing.JLabel RegLbl;
    private javax.swing.JButton RegisterBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TextArea;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

//This is where im stuck this is the window i want to asked the user for their account number but i dont know how to achieve this 

 public Transaction( ) {
        initComponents();

    }
 Transaction (BankAccount acc1,ArrayList CustomerList,Integer accNum)
 {
     Acc1=acc1;
     CustList=CustomerList;
     accountNumber=accNum;

 }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        AccNumTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        AccBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Please Enter your Account Number");

        AccBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Onyx", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        AccBtn.setText("Enter");
        AccBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AccBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(AccNumTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 181, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(104, 104, 104))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(AccBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(151, 151, 151))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(AccNumTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(AccBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void AccBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         Integer accountNumber=Integer.parseInt(AccNumTxt.getText());
         for(Object o: CustomerList){
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Transaction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Transaction().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton AccBtn;
        private javax.swing.JTextField AccNumTxt;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is make a `BankManager` class in a [Singleton Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/) which contains a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that uses the `BankAccount` as the Value and the `Account Number` as the Key. From there, you can easily grab the `BankManager` instance from anywhere in your program to query for the `BankAccount`.

Comment: Your code "example" is way too big. Is that only one class?

Comment: Also, I think you have your `Customer` and `BankAccount` relationship backwards. A `Customer` should logically be able to have multiple `BankAccount` objects related to it, so you should add a `Customer` object to your `BankAccount` class for navigation to the `Customer` and a collection of `BankAccount` objects to the `Customer` class for navigation to the `BankAccount` objects.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen No its multiple classes

Comment: @TimHunter i am relatively new,I am a student so im probably gonna make these mistake and also thank you i see if this can help me

Answer (score 0):

Lot of things are not taken into consideration for a banking application. However, I am keeping that aside as I am not aware of the scope of your assignment.

At the outset, if parallel operations are allowed on a particular bank account like withdrawal and deposit can happen together or in parallel, you should consider using your data structure which supports multi-threading and can function in a synchronised manner. Though arraylist does not seem to be the right data structure, still if you insist on using that, try using copyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList and in case you choose to use maps for faster operations - use concurrentHashMap.

If you are facing a visibility problem, you can have public getters/setters for your List.

Comment: Its a requiremnt for the assignment "Use array or ArrayList to allow the user to store as many customer objects as he or she requires.". Its also a basic program its to build a gui for the bankAccount and customer class i already had which i provided

Comment: "Use array or ArrayList to allow the user to store as many customer objects as he or she requires" - should use ArrayList since their size is not restricted and it can save as many as he/she requires.